# Sending email through resque: object treated as hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, resque

I'm sending emails out through resque. All emails send properly except this one, which sends fine in development locally but fails on staging server.

It seems to view the 'Admin' object as a hash instead of treating it as an admin object. Any ideas?

account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_commit :send_welcome_email

    def send_welcome_email
      SubscriptionNotifier.welcome(self).deliver
    end

end
```

subscription_notifier.rb

```
class SubscriptionNotifier < ActionMailer::Base

  def welcome(account)
    @subscriber = account
    mail(:to => account.admin.email, :subject => "Welcome!")
  end

end
```

Resque error

```
SubscriptionNotifier Arguments

    "welcome"
    {"account"=>{"address_line1"=>nil, "address_line2"=>nil, "city"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2012-02-08T10:56:22-08:00", "currency"=>"United States Dollar (USD)", "deleted_at"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "email"=>"test2@test.com", "full_domain"=>"www.test.net", "id"=>3, "initial_plan"=>nil, "latitude"=>nil, "longitude"=>nil, "name"=>"macs", "phone"=>nil, "setup_steps_complete"=>0, "state"=>nil, "time_zone"=>"Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "updated_at"=>"2012-02-08T10:56:22-08:00", "website"=>nil, "zip"=>nil}}

Exception
    NoMethodError
Error
    undefined method `admin' for #<Hash:0x0000000585aa70>
```

Comment: What's the code you're using to actually call `SubscriptionNotifier.welcome(...).deliver`?

Comment: Can you add the Resque worker code and show how you're calling it?

Comment: I updated the post. The Resque worker code is what's in subscription_notifier. It's as if the Rails env isn't loaded, but I'm starting it with 'rake resque:work QUEUE='*' RAILS_ENV=staging'

Comment: I'm confused... you should have a worker somewhere with a `def self.perform` method which then calls your SubscriptionNotifier. Somewhere, probably there, there must be a `SubscriptionNotifier.welcome...` method call?

Comment: Doh, forgot to put that in account.rb in the post. Added it above.

Comment: The problem was b/c you have to pass id's only, through resque. It won't know about the objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just pass in the account ID into the queue and have the worker fetch the Account object when it does its perform method. That should lessen your Hash woes.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but still relevant. The answers here give workarounds, but don't describe why the problem arises or how to design jobs to avoid it.

Basically for Resque to persist jobs in Redis, the arguments need to be serialized so they can be saved. You can't save a Ruby object in a database (for example), so the arguments are serialized to JSON (which can be persisted). In your case, it's calling `account.to_json` and stores that as an argument to your job.

The likely reason this is an issue in staging but not in development, is your development Redis is only storing the jobs in memory (and therefore they don't need to be serialized). Staging is persisting them to disk or a database for example, so they have to be serialized.

To avoid this problem, arguments to jobs should be strings, numbers, or data structures that can be converted to json.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide a thorough explanation to this question from a while back.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load the environment by running 'rake environment resque:work QUEUE='*' RAILS_ENV=staging'

that is unless you have

task "resque:setup" => :environment

defined in a resque.rake file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in account.rb

```
   def send_welcome_email
      SubscriptionNotifier.welcome(self.admin.email).deliver
    end
```

in subscription_notifier.rb

```
 def welcome(account_admin_email)
    @subscriber = account 
    mail(:to => account_admin_email, :subject => "Welcome!")
  end
```

I had the same error, apparently you are passing `account` as a hash and it has no email `admin` method. So just get the email in the send_welcome_email method and pass it as a parameter, instead to passing a hash and trying to access the email in the welcome method.

NOTE: for the @subscriber, you would need to pass the parameters, just like the email, you use in the email template for example `self.admin.name` in the model and `@name = account_admin_name` in the welcome method

Hope this helps.